# DDD design+ Immutability when using event sourcing good idea?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, immutability, microservices, event-sourcing

This is my third question on DDD and event sourcing.I was looking into some best practices and unrelated to DDD a good concept is to make your classes immutable if possible.

I however see a problem in my head trying to marry Event sourcing pattern + immutable Domain Model. Since

**DomainModel-1.0 + e1  = DomainModel-2.0**
[rinse and repeat for all events]

My concern is if I implement my domain model as immutable will I not be creating a lot of domain objects just for my domain model to be up to date and that is wasted resources.

I want to know what if there is any upside to make my Domain model immutable if I am planning to use in with event sourcing.

Answer (score 1):

> Immutability when using event sourcing good idea?

Yes.

> My concern is if I implement my domain model as immutable will I not be creating a lot of domain objects just for my domain model to be up to date and that is wasted resources.

That's so.  Are those wasted resources expensive?  Have you measured?

> I want to know what if there is any upside to make my Domain model immutable if I am planning to use in with event sourcing.

The biggest is concurrency -- sharing state between concurrent operations is much easier to get correct when the state is immutable.  Consequently, immutable state is a lot easier to share - you don't need to make fresh copies of data just in case you hit a branch that wants to change things.

Operations on immutable state are a lot easier to test, and a lot easier to test in isolation (if you squint, this is really the same point as above, in a slightly different context).